# ConTeXt Nested Frames: inner offset shrinks frames

Tags: context, framed, bugs

```
\starttext
\framed[strut=no,offset=0pt,rulethickness=1pt]{%
\framed
    [align=normal,
     width=200pt,
     height=50pt,
     offset=0pt,
     frame=off,
     rulethickness=0pt]{%
    \blackrule[color=orange,width=100pt,height=50pt]}}
\stoptext
```

[image: good]

So far everything is OK. The thickness of the rule should be set to 0pt otherwise it adds 0.4pt spacing even when the frame is off - according to `\framedwidth`. Unfortunately I can't seem to add any offset; doing so shrinks both boxes:

```
\starttext
\framed[strut=no,offset=0pt,rulethickness=1pt]{%
\framed
    [align=normal,
     width=200pt,
     height=50pt,
     offset=10pt,
     frame=off,
     rulethickness=0pt]{%
    \blackrule[color=orange,width=100pt,height=50pt]}}
\stoptext
```

[image: bad]

Note that the default offset, 2.5ex, seems to work just fine.

```
\framed[strut=no,offset=0pt,rulethickness=1pt]{%
\framed
    [align=normal,
     width=200pt,
     height=50pt,
     frame=off,
     rulethickness=0pt]{%
    \blackrule[color=orange,width=100pt,height=50pt]}}
```

[image: default]

The expected output, just as if the frame was not nested:

[image: target]

Comment: Is it necessary to have a `\framed` inside a `\framed`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The inner framed is actually a table. I simplified it to a frame for this MWE.

Comment: What is actually the expected output here?

Comment: Just like the default, but configurable. In other words, the same as a non-nested frame (updated the question).

Comment: You should turn the frame of the inner `\framed` on again and then play around with `offset` to see what happens.  I think that should give you a clearer understanding of what is going on here.

Comment: I don't follow. When I do that it behaves as expected and just like the default. The boxes remain the same size, and the blackrule is shifted. Of course I also had to use a non-zero rule thickness.

Comment: The `offset` is added between the frame and the content by subtracting `offset` from `width` and `height`, i.e. shrinking the content.  Try setting `width=220pt,height=70pt,offset=10pt`, i.e. adding the offset to width and height.

Comment: I see the confusion - the blackrule is just an impromptu visual measuring stick that I added afterwards. When I added the offset to the inner `\framed` I expected the `\framedwidth` and `\framedheight` to decrease. I did not expect the boxes shrink - specifically the outer frame. The expected behavior would be as in any non-nested `\framed`: the offset pushes the `\blackrule` towards the bottom-right, beyond the visible frame while the boxes remain the same size.

Comment: No, that is not how TeX works.  There is no such things as “the offset pushes to the bottom-right”.  What has to be done at a low level is to box things up and adjust width, height, and depth such that things show up at the bottom-right.  Whenever you are doing some alignment it's essentially just trimming boxes.

Comment: Updated to show the expected output. I don't know how the boxes are typeset in TeX, but the *effect* is to move the contents to the bottom-right, and that is the abstraction I believe ConTeXt is going for. So is the behavior I've outlined a bug in ConTeXt? The inner `\framed` must be offset since it represents multiple table cells which require individual offsets.

Comment: Is using `[tlrb]offset` the only workaround? Is it possible to set them all at once, `toffset=loffset`? Or `toffset=\framedparameter{loffset}`?

Comment: Have you had a look at my answer?

Comment: I can see that it works but I don't understand it. Are you saying that `offset` shrinks the content and that is why the outer frame shrank? But `[tblr]offset` also shrinks the content, according to `\framedwidth` and `\framedheight` (and these values are the same within either box). To me it just looks like you are working around a bug. If otherwise can you explain?

Comment: I don't develop ConTeXt, I don't know whether this is a bug, but this is the current behaviour and I accept it.  If you think this is a bug you can take it to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `offset`, the offset is added by shrinking the content.  To achieve the effect you want, you have to add the offset by enlarging the content.  This is done using the `[tblr]offset` keys.

```
\starttext
\framed[strut=no,rulethickness=1pt]{%
\framed
    [align=normal,
     width=200pt,
     height=50pt,
     toffset=10pt,
     boffset=\framedparameter{toffset},
     loffset=\framedparameter{toffset},
     roffset=\framedparameter{toffset},
     frame=off,
     rulethickness=0pt]{%
    \blackrule[color=orange,width=100pt,height=50pt]}}
\stoptext
```

[image]

You can set all parameters at once using a macro in `extras`.

```
\define[1]\setouteroffset{%
    \setframedparameter{toffset}{#1}%
    \setframedparameter{boffset}{#1}%
    \setframedparameter{loffset}{#1}%
    \setframedparameter{toffset}{#1}%
}
\starttext
\framed[strut=no,rulethickness=1pt]{%
\framed
    [align=normal,
     width=200pt,
     height=50pt,
     extras=\setouteroffset{10pt},
     frame=off,
     rulethickness=0pt]{%
    \blackrule[color=orange,width=100pt,height=50pt]}}
\stoptext
```

Comment: The `extras` macro isn't working for me.

Comment: @user19087 Works in latest ConTeXt standalone.  I haven't tried it with LMTX.

Comment: @user19087 Works also in latest LMTX.

Comment: It works with `\framed`. It has no effect with `\bTABLE`, though no error either. Setting `[lrtb]offset` does work. Is there a version of `extras` that works with tables?

Comment: Probably not...